# Regex match multiple authors separated by commas

Tags: regex

What's the regex expression to match

Goóep

Frop, Lop

SçΩpo, Íp, Ågdo

*but not*

ßapé,

SçΩpo, Íp, Ågdo,

Comment: Why should one be matched and not the other? What are the rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\p{L}+( *, *\p{L}+)*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH1rD1/1)

Answer (score 0):

`\p{L}`  matches any unicode letter, in your case, you could use:

```
\p{L}+
```